# Embedded console view for Recepient

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a webservice (.NET) which makes all the calls (gets the envelope info etc.) & gets the recipient view URL. I am trying to open this URL in a new browser window so that that signing process can start.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( url);

This works fine in VS2013 dev environment but when published to the IIS server(Win2008 server), the process start does not work. I was wondering if anyone has used the recipient view in web application(ASP.NET / webservice) - & how did they manage to get this working after publishing to the web server.

Thanks in advance.

JK

Answer (score 0):

The URL returned via DocuSign API in response to a "Request Recipient View" request is simply a URL like any other -- so this isn't really a DocuSign-specific question, but rather, a question related to how to accomplish opening a URL in a new browser window within the context of the dev technology that you're using. You might want to add more tags to your question (other than just DocuSign API) to have better odds of getting your question answered.

That being said -- if your goal is simply to launch a new window (with the target URL you specify) from an ASP.NET page, you might consider one of the following approaches:

- using the **onClientClick** parameter (as illustrated in this thread
  [How to launch another aspx web page upon button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366243/how-to-launch-another-aspx-web-page-upon-button-click)) if a user action (ex: button click) should trigger the opening of the URL in new window
- using **Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript** in code-behind to open the window via regular javascript semantics (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)