# How to use a page after opening another page with target=_blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can open another window to display some stuff, but then I cannot use the buttons on the original page anymore. Why is this and how to fix it? This is my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_ViewSimpleRequest" Text="Simple Request" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank'"  PostBackUrl="~/xyz.aspx" />
<asp:Button ID="Button_Self" Text="Self" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_self'" />
```

After clicking the first button, the second button also redirects to xyz.aspx. How do I make the second button behave like a normal button on the original page?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This guy has a very good aproach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366243/how-to-launch-another-aspx-web-page-upon-button-click

Comment: I tried: `<asp:Button ID="Button_ViewSimpleRequest" Text="Simple Request" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('xyz.aspx', 'name')" />` which is less code, simpler, and seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried: `<asp:Button ID="Button_ViewSimpleRequest" Text="Simple Request" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('xyz.aspx', 'name')" />` which is simple, and seems to work.

I found my solution by studying [How to launch another aspx web page upon button click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366243/how-to-launch-another-aspx-web-page-upon-button-click)