# C# Web Application Page Load with Method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a web application with two pages at the moment, The first page the user needs to complete some details, with a button that needs to open the second page with a list of buildings and the user needs to choose one of to populate a list of textboxes in the first form.

My question is, from a button on the first page. (CreateSurvey.aspx) I want to open the second page (Search_Property.aspx)

I have come across syntax like

```
Search_Property Search = new Search_Property();

        Search.open();
```

But the .open does not exist in this context.

Could someone help me please.

Regards

Rob

Answer (score 1):

In Web forms, you open pages by redirecting to the new page. So, in your button click event, you would use:

`Response.Redirect("Search_Property.aspx");` or
`Server.Transfer("Search_Property.aspx");`

And of course there's the option to modify your button markup to post directly to Search_property.aspx as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976700/474702):

`<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" PostBackUrl="~/Search_Property.aspx" />`

Comment: Thank you very much, after searching for ages I just found the exact same thing.  But thank you again.

Comment: i found this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366243/how-to-launch-another-aspx-web-page-upon-button-click

Comment: does it answer your question?

Comment: yes it does, but i may have something else in relation to this very soon.

Comment: If it answers this question, mark it as such, when you get something else, ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to navigate to another page and then back again, there are several options.  You can create HTML "dialogs" in your `CreateSurvey.aspx` page and show/hide them as necessary.  You can also use an `IFRAME` on the `CreateSurvey.aspx` page to display the `Search_Property.aspx` page and then use some `Ajax` (`HttpXmlRequest`) to update the `CreateSurvey.aspx` page.