# Input field open in new Tab with OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Input Field. When I click on this field it will add product into the Cart and moves on the Cart Page.

```
<input type="button" class="bgbutton"
value="Add to Shopping Cart" id="addtocart" name="addtocart"
onkeypress="window.event.cancelBubble=true;"
onclick="if (document.forms['form590'].onsubmit()) { document.forms['form590'].submit(); } return false;"
target="_blank">
```

I have given the tag `target` but unfortunately it does not work.
Kindly give me any Solution in JQuery / JavaScript etc.

**SOLUTION**

Simply I add target attribute in form tag. that's it.

```
$("form").attr("target", "_blank");
```

I resolved my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Target is an anchor tag attribute.

Comment: @skdroid it can also be used in form tags.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Drewskis `action` is different and the `target` is different. the `action` allows submitting form into the given URL while `target` only open the new window

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can use anchor tag instead of the button

```
<a
     href="CART_URL" <-- here goes cart url you want to open in the new tab
     class="bgbutton"
     id="addtocart"
     name="addtocart"
     onkeypress="window.event.cancelBubble=true;"
     onclick="document.forms['form590'].onsubmit() ? document.forms['form590'].submit() :; return false;"
     target="_blank"
>Add to Shopping Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To open a new tab you can use the following code.

```
<input type="button" class="bgbutton" value="Add to Shopping Cart" id="addtocart" name="addtocart" onkeypress="window.event.cancelBubble=true;" onclick="window.open('NewPage.aspx', 'NewPage');" >
```

To move between pages

```
<input type="button" class="bgbutton" value="Add to Shopping Cart" id="addtocart" name="addtocart" onkeypress="window.event.cancelBubble=true;" onclick="location.href = 'NewPage.aspx';" >
```

For more details you may want to refer to the following questions:

- [How to launch another aspx web page upon button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7366346/9560041)
- [How can I make a button redirect my page to another page? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562671/9560041)

In JQuery you can use the following

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".bgbutton").click(function () {
                window.location.href = "NewPage.aspx";
            });
        });

</script>
```

You can carry the variables to the other page through the URL like below.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name = "coder";

            $(".bgbutton").click(function () {
                window.location = 'NewPage.aspx?username=' + name;
            });
        });

 </script>
```

To get the passed values to open up in new tab use the following

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name = "coder";

            $(".bgbutton").click(function () {
                window.open('NewPage.aspx?username=' + name,"")
            });
        });

 </script>
```

In order to understand how to retrieve a value from a URL, you might want to refer to the following question: [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

Comment: Can you show me how you are doing it? It would be great if you can share your script file

Comment: @JohnBrad What does not work for you? Coder is explaining things quite correctly. Just using `window.location` in JavaScript will solve the problem for you. You do not want to use the `target` HTML attribute.

Comment: My Onclick Code. onclick="if (document.forms['form590'].onsubmit()) { document.forms['form590'].submit(); } return false;" is not working in window.open.

Comment: When I use $(".bgbutton").click. it is going on Cart Page. I want it will be open in new Tab. Second after using this, My Add to Functionality does not work.

Comment: @JohnBrad why do you use that if condition? please show me the code of adding to your cart

Comment: Its a NetSuite Application. This application works like that. If condition is produced through NetSuite Tag.